# How to do a debug for serenity projects

Tags: serenity-bdd

I have created a new project (infact its a default project of serenity). 
[image]
Screenshot 1

[image]
Screenshot 2

in the maven run configuration i have only added 
clean verify 
This runs the project without any issue
but i want to debug the code in eclipse at the added breakpoint (as in screenshot 1)
is there any configuration i need to add to the maven run configurations so as to debug the serenity projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution

Right click on project
Debug as -> Maven build ...
In the goals field put **-Dmaven.surefire.debug test**
In the parameters put a new parameter called **forkCount** with a value of **0**

Answer (score 1):

## Serenity and JBehave

If you are using JBehave, you can run an individual story in Debug mode by creating a class that

For example, if you have a story called `buy_milk.story` or `buyMilk.story`, you can create a class called `BuyMilk` that extends `SerenityStories`:

```
public class BuyMilk extends SerenityStories {}
```

Then just run this class in Debug mode.

## Serenity and Cucumber

If you are using Cucumber, just use the `@CucumberOptions` to identify the tags and/or feature file(s) you want to run, e.g. to run only the scenarios or features marked with the `@current` tag, you could write a class like this:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        tags = {"@current"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features"
)
public class Current {}
```